# Convert .GDB file to .shp file

Tags: python, type-conversion

I have a .gdb folder with LOCK Files, FREELIST Files, ATX Files, GDBINDEXES Files, GDBTABLE Files, GDBTABLEX Files and, SPX Files.

I want to convert them to .shp files.

Could you tell me the required codes?

Thanks.

Comment: This kind of question is off topic on SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic